# asyncio.gather with selective return_exceptions

Tags: python-asyncio

I want for `asyncio.gather` to immediately raise any exception except for some particular exception class, which should be instead returned in the results list. Right now, I just slightly modified the canonical implementation of `asyncio.gather` in CPython and use that, but I wonder if there is not a more canonical way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement such semantics using the more powerful `asyncio.wait` primitive and its `return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION` option:

```py
async def xgather(*coros, allowed_exc):
    results = {}
    pending = futures = list(map(asyncio.ensure_future, coros))
    while pending:
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
            pending, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION)
        for fut in done:
            try:
                results[fut] = fut.result()
            except allowed_exc as e:
                results[fut] = e
    return [results[fut] for fut in futures]
```

The idea is to call `wait` until either all futures are done or an exception is observed. The exception is in turn either stored or propagated, depending on whether it matches `allowed_exc`. If all the results and allowed exceptions have been successfully collected, they are returned in the correct order, as with `asyncio.gather`.

The approach of modifying the implementation of `asyncio.gather` might easily fail on a newer Python version, since the code accesses private attributes of `Future` objects. Also, alternative event loops like `uvloop` could make their `gather` and `wait` more efficient, which would automatically benefit an `xgather` based on the public API.

Test code:

```py
import asyncio

async def fail():
    1/0

async def main():
    print(await xgather(asyncio.sleep(1), fail(), allowed_exc=OSError))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

When run, the code raises immediately, which is expected `ZeroDivisionError` doesn't match the allowed `OSError` exception. Changing `OSError` to `ZeroDivisionError` causes the code to sleep for 1 second and output `[None, ZeroDivisionError('division by zero',)]`.

Comment: Great! Thanks. I thought of using `asyncio.wait`, but didn't think of your simple way of returning the results in order.

Comment: Which I really should have, because that's exactly how `asyncio.gather` does it...

Comment: Here the early call to `asyncio.ensure_future` is essential, because otherwise `asyncio.wait` would do it for us (it will anyway, but it will be no-op if we do it first) and then we couldn't match the futures in `results` to the original ones.

Comment: @azag0 In the source I have checked out they allocate a list of `[None] * nchildren` and schedules each `_done_callback` with the appropriate index into the list. Now I've pulled the latest sources and it seems that they modified it a couple of months ago to make it [faster](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/36c2c044782997520df7fc5604742a615ccf6b17).

Comment: @azag0 The latest code uses the `arg_to_fut` dict only to handle the case of receiving the same coro/future twice in the argument list. The `children` are correctly ordered to begin with, so they don't need my final pass. (They do have to do a lot of other stuff which I get away with by calling `wait`.) I wonder if `asyncio.gather` could also be implemented in terms of `wait`. I suppose it would be less efficient.)

Comment: I've [tested](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/pub.janhermann.cz/e3/bcf874d3/Untitled.ipynb) on a list of 10,000 coroutines, and there doesn't seem to be any noticeable difference between `asyncio.gather` and its equivalent implemented using `asyncio.wait`.

Comment: One can further make `xgather` behave more like `asyncio.gather` by cancelling all the other tasks when exception is raised, by adding
```python
            except Exception as e:
                for fut in futures:
                    fut.cancel()
                raise```

Comment: @azag0 Good catch, I've now amended the answer to include the modification.

Comment: @jhrmnn It has come to my attention that the last two comments do not reflect the behavior of `gather` correctly. `gather` in fact **doesn't** cancel the other tasks when one task raises. Instead, it propagates the exception, but lets the other tasks blindly carry on. It was [suggested to change](https://bugs.python.org/issue31452) this behavior, but the change was rejected because it's not backward compatible. Instead, it should be handled by a new `TaskGroup` primitive similar to Trio's [nurseries](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-core.html#nurseries-and-spawning).